Sunburst in Mermaid/multi-level pie chart
I've seen some nice nice sunburst diagrams, e.g., or multi-level pie charts, like this,

But, I haven't been able to find  code to make such diagrams in mermaid. Only regular one level pie chart diagrams, i.e. from here,
pie title Pets adopted by volunteers
    "Dogs" : 386
    "Cats" : 85
    "Rats" : 15


Any ideas on how I can make a sunburst diagram in mermaid? Alternatively, some sunburst that can render in GitLab, seems to be mermaid exclusively.

I'm not sure how much you need to stick to those particular packages, but if you need such complex diagrams, then take a look at ECharts.

You’re going to have to extend mermaid by adding this chart type, or do as others have said and host it externally then link to that from your markdown. There was a poll about new charts and someone mentioned sunburst but to no avail: https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues/177#issuecomment-1629718813

I know the question is not related to ECharts, but it can be implemented with it as well.


/**
 ** Initialize
 */
const chartDom = document.getElementById('chart');
const chart = echarts.init(chartDom);

/**
 ** Data
 */
const generateData = (year) => {
  const isLeapYear = (year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 !== 0) || (year % 400 === 0);
  const daysInMonth = [31, isLeapYear ? 29 : 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
  const monthNames = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

  const data = [{
    name: 'Year',
    children: []
  }];

  let weekCount = 1; // Initialize week counter

  Array.from({ length: 4 }, (_, q) => {
    const quarterObj = { name: `Q${q + 1}`, children: [] };
    data[0].children.push(quarterObj);

    Array.from({ length: 3 }, (_, m) => {
      const monthIndex = m + q * 3; // Calculate month index
      const monthObj = { name: monthNames[monthIndex], children: [] };
      quarterObj.children.push(monthObj);

      let dayCount = 1; // Initialize day counter

      Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(daysInMonth[monthIndex] / 7) }, (_, w) => {
        const weekObj = { name: `Week ${weekCount}`, children: [] };
        monthObj.children.push(weekObj);

        const startDay = (w * 7 + 1 < dayCount) ? dayCount : w * 7 + 1;
        const endDay = Math.min((w + 1) * 7, daysInMonth[monthIndex]);

        Array.from({ length: endDay - startDay + 1 }, (_, d) => {
          const dayObj = { name: `Day ${dayCount}`, value: 1 };
          weekObj.children.push(dayObj);
          dayCount++;
        });

        weekCount++;
      });
    });
  });

  return data;
};

const data = generateData(2024);

/**
 ** Option
 */
const option = {
  series: [{
    type: 'sunburst',
    data: data[0].children,
    radius: [70, '90%'],
    label: {
      rotate: 'radial',
      minAngle: 5
    },
    itemStyle: {
      borderRadius: 7,
      borderWidth: 2
    },
  }]
};

/**
 ** Render Chart
 */
chart.setOption(option);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.5.0/echarts.min.js" integrity="sha512-k37wQcV4v2h6jgYf5IUz1MoSKPpDs630XGSmCaCCOXxy2awgAWKHGZWr9nMyGgk3IOxA1NxdkN8r1JHgkUtMoQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="chart" style="width: 700px; height: 700px;"></div>




This is very nice, but does it  render in GitLab?

@EricFail To the best of my knowledge, no. However, you can host the diagram on an external site and link to its access in markdown. Alternatively, you can take a screenshot of the created diagram and attach it as a photo. I'm not sure exactly what you need, but the diagrams provided by GitLab are not as complex, so I don't see any other way.

Thank you for your answer here.  I am, as I wrote in my question, looking for a sunburst diagram in mermaid or alternately, something that can render in GitLab.

The "Mermaid" tool in Gitlab is actually using graphviz.
You could look into creating User-defined Node Shapes to build a starburst.
